# Dropdownbox getting values concatenated

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

How do I get the values in the dropdownbox splitted and not concatenated? In a project, I populated a dropdownbox with values from the database when I run the project, the values are all concatenated, not appearing as a list in the dropdownbox. What I want is for them to appear as a list not concatenated. I think the attached image would better explain what I mean.

[image]

The DAO code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> allCities() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT first_name FROM User").list(); 
    }
```

The controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView getRegisterForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, Object> models = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    models.put("user", userService.allCities());
    return new ModelAndView("Register", "models", models);
}
```

The jsp page:

```
![<td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="city" items="${models}"></form:select></td>][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
models.put("users", userService.allCities());
```

And JSP

```
<form:select path="city" items="${users}" itemValue="userId" itemLabel="userName"></form:select>
```

I assume that User has 2 getters: getUserId() and getUserName()

This link will help you

```
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/
```

Comment: Thanks, Loc. As you know that this is returning a model type so users would not have been an option.

Comment: I just added itemValue, itemLabel. You can re-test

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the concatenated array was that I did not perform any iteration on it before binding it in the JSP file. Just need to rewrite the code for the controller thus and change the placeholder in the jsp file based on the name the object is named:

The controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView getRegisterForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
        Object collectList = null;
        ArrayList<Object> arrayListing = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayListing.add(userService.allCities());
        for(Object objectList : arrayListing)
        {
            collectList = objectList;
        }   
    return new ModelAndView("Register", "collectList", collectList);    
    }
```

The JSP code:

```
<td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="city" items="${collectList}"></form:select></td>
```